# How to remove colliding box2d bodies in AndEngine?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm using AndEngine to create a game with box2d extension. I want to implement a condition that when two bodies collide, they should be removed or respawned. Initially I tried using

```
if(sprite1.collidesWith(sprite2))
// remove the sprites
```

but this doesnt seem to help because the sprites are attached to their respective bodies. I also tried using contactListener as follows:

```
bodyA=getFixtureA().getBody();
bodyB=getFixtureB().getBody();
```

and then later

```
if(bodyA!=null && bodyB!=null)
// remove the bodies
```

but that crashed the game. Does anybody know a better way of doing it?

Comment: If my answer helps you than please dont forgot to accept my answer and up vote me it will be much appreciated . Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If the Sprite collision actually occurs, you can remove the bodies as well at the same time:

```
mPhysicsWorld.getPhysicsConnectorManager().findPhysicsConnectorByShape(pSprite);
```